# datagridview datasource not binding when change

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding

My code works fine but when I add data to datagridview it not binding to gridview. I didn't understand. When I search some I find BindingSource.If ı use this I have to change lots of things of my code. are there some shortcuts of binding to datagridview

This is loading datagridview

`schoolGridView.DataSource = load.GetDataSource();`

And this is when I adding row.

```
List<DataSourceObject> src = (List < DataSourceObject >)schoolGridView.DataSource;
        DataSourceObject dat = new DataSourceObject();
        dat.sinif = "asd";
        dat.okulAdi = "ad";
        dat.ogrenciAdi = "123";
        dat.ilce = "43";
        dat.il = "123";

        src.Add(dat);

        schoolGridView.DataSource = src;
```

Comment: The DGV does not automaticaly repaint when the DataSource is changed.  The trick to get the DGV to update is set the Datsource to null and then back to the actual source.   schoolGridView.DataSource = null; schoolGridView.DataSource = src;

Comment: The only way I consistently get DataGridViews to update from a datasource is to insert a BindingSource into the mix.  You make the BindingSource the datasource of the DGV, then you assign your backing source (typically a `List<T>`) the datasource of the BindingSource.  Whenever you want the DGV to update you call `theBindingSource.ResetBinding(false);`.  It usually works like a charm and really isn't that hard to refit into an app

Comment: @jdweng thanks man that's I have been looking for

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried `BindingList<>` generic class that are simillar to `List<>` class? BindingList are more suitable for role of DataSource. I belive you can also benefit from methods like `GridView.Invalidate()`, `GridView.Update()` and `GridView.Refresh()`. You can find more information in [DataGridView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2).